# How to redirect to the successs page upon successfull http post request in angular Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am learning how to use angular javascript alongside my favorite, PHP framework (CodeIgniter). I have a login section that authenticates to a service and gets the response using angular js. The code works fine. See snippet below

```
var login = angular.module('authenticationApp' , ['ngMaterial' , 'ngRoute']) ;

    login.controller('authenticationController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.authenticate = function () {

            if ($scope.username == undefined || $scope.password == undefined) {
                $scope.login_error_message = "All form fields are required" ;

            } else {
                var url = get_base_url() + 'student/authentication/login?username=' + $scope.username + '&password=' + $scope.password ;

                $http.post(url).then(
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(response) ;
                        /*Here I handle success*/                           
                    }, function (response) {
                        $scope.login_error_message = "Service Error!. Response: " + response ;
                    }
                ) ;
            }
        } ;
```

My problem is how can I send that response to the success.php page and also redirect to the success page. I can redirect using

```
 window.location.href = get_base_url() + 'administrator/authentication/dashboard' ;
```

My challenge now is actually sending the response to this new location.

Thanks in advance and I am ready to provide more details if need be

Answer (score 0):

After battling for long, I just decided to use plain js. Crappy but works.